# On Ruby on Rails, how to run ONE functional test when another one is breaking?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, functional-testing

let's say you added a controller and action (example: `story/index`), and want to run a functional test by

```
rake test:functionals
```

and then you found that another part of the project your coworker is working on actually broke the test at an earlier place (another controller/action), before your functional test takes place.

In this case, can you run just one functional test, which is yours?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Wise-Ass Answer**
If you coworker breaks the tests, then he should fix the test, or he shouldn't have committed the code to the repo. That is the main principle that we usually have in projects I work on.

**Nice Answer**
Try this

```
rake test:functionals TEST=test/functional/xy_test.rb
```

Or this
running one test without rake but with explicit $-loadpath works too
here "ruby -I directory" specifies the $loadpath. Otherwise you won't load test environment and "require test_helper" fails!

```
ruby -I test test/functional/xy_test.rb
```

Comment: @動靜能量 try `rake test TEST=test/functional/xy_test.rb`

Answer (score 0):

1) Perhaps: rake test:units

2) This link might also help you out:

http://rake.rubyforge.org/

3) This might also help you out:

> "Typical Rails tests come in the
>   follow forms:
>
> Unit (Model) These test business logic
>   in your models. A well-written Rails
>   application should have the bulk of
>   its code in its models, so the bulk of
>   your tests should be these.
>
> Functional (Controller) These test
>   individual controller actions in
>   isolation.
>
> Integration (Controller to Controller)
>   These test state mutations
>   between/over multiple actions and
>   routing, i.e. ensuring that things
>   don’t totally explode as a user clicks
>   through a typical work flow.
>
> Fixtures Used to hold example model
>   data used to easily instantiate those
>   models in tests, avoiding the tedious
>   process of manually creating model
>   objects.
>
> Unit/Helpers These test helpers used
>   in views.
>
> In other words, the basic
>   relationships look like this:
>
> Model Unit Test Controller    Functional
>   Test View (as part of a) Functional
>   Test Controller to
>   Controller    Integration Test"

Found at http://rails-nutshell.labs.oreilly.com/ch09.html

Comment: unit test really is for testing models... functional is for testing controllers and views... they are the M V C in the MVC framework.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [single_test](https://github.com/grosser/single_test) gem which makes it easy to run specific tests (or groups of tests)